# ¿porque esta ruta https://shopp-app.test/password/email me da error en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]este es el error que me da, deberia agregar una ruta en web.php?

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'TestController@welcome');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/search', 'SearchController@show');
Route::get('/products/json', 'SearchController@data');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@contact');
Route::get('/us', 'UsController@us');
Route::get('/products/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
Route::get('/categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@show');

Route::post('/cart', 'CartDetailController@store');
Route::delete('/cart', 'CartDetailController@destroy');
Route::post('/order', 'CartController@update');

Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function (){
  Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index'); //listado
  Route::get('/products/create', 'ProductController@create'); //ver el formulario de registro
  Route::post('/products', 'ProductController@store'); //registrar nuevos productos
  Route::get('/products/{id}/edit', 'ProductController@edit'); // ver el formulario para editar
  Route::post('/products/{id}/edit', 'ProductController@update');// hacer un update del producto
  Route::delete('/products/{id}', 'ProductController@destroy'); // elimina el producto

  Route::get('/products/{id}/images', 'ImageController@index');
  Route::post('/products/{id}/images', 'ImageController@store');
  Route::delete('/products/{id}/images', 'ImageController@destroy');
  Route::get('/products/{id}/images/select/{image}', 'ImageController@select'); //destacar una imagen

  Route::get('/categories', 'CategoryController@index'); //listado
  Route::get('/categories/create', 'CategoryController@create'); //ver el formulario de registro
  Route::post('/categories', 'CategoryController@store'); //registrar nuevos productos
  Route::get('/categories/{category}/edit', 'CategoryController@edit'); // ver el formulario para editar
  Route::post('/categories/{category}/edit', 'CategoryController@update');// hacer un update del producto
  Route::delete('/categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@destroy'); // elimina el producto
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de ser así que ruta agrego y en que parte?

Comment: el error te esta diciendo que el metodo con el que has llamado a esa url no esta aceptado. Por ej, esa ruta responde a un POST y tu estas llamando con GET. (ojo, que es un ejemplo).

Comment: no estoy llamando nada en web.php ni "/password/reset" ni "/password/email" porque pense que con make:auth ya se creaban las rutas necesarias, que deberia agregar? @Jakala

Comment: No tienes que agregar nada, la ruta funciona. La pregunta es, como estás intentando acceder a ella?

Comment: escribiendo https://shopp-app.test/password/email en el navegador

Comment: con el https://

Comment: si lo estas haciendo con el navegador, lo mas seguro es que estes haciendo una llamada GET. En principio no es problema. Simplemente que no hay respuesta para esa ruta con esa accion. Puedes probar con PostMan a enviar un POST a esa url, para ver que sucede... De momento, en la consola escribe el comando: `php artisan route:list` para ver que informacion te dice de la ruta en cuestion

Comment: osea que el problema esta en el Auth::routes(); o donde, que ruta debo agregar? @Jakala

Comment: Primero ejecuta el comando anterior y publica la respuesta del comando para esa ruta. A ver si tenemos algo mas de informacion... Sigo diciendo: como tal no parece un problema, pero tenemos que definir a) como vas a llamar y b) si la ruta responde a la accion correcta

Comment: @Jakala ya añadi la imagen con las rutas, ayudame por favor :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que hay algo de confusión en el tema de la ruta en especifico, explicare un poco donde reside el problema.

Las rutas están bien, estas intentando acceder a una ruta POST mediante GET, si por lo que sea necesitas que esta sea GET, puedes añadir esta ruta a web:

```
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
```

Pero entonces tendrás otro error, ya que esta ruta, necesita que le envies parametros para saber a donde enviar el email de recuperación.

Como ya he dicho, no entiendo porque necesitas acceder por GET a esa ruta, solo envía un correo de recuperación de contraseña.

Comment: entonces la forma de acceder es la incorrecta? un usuario comun no accederia de esta forma?

Comment: No, un usuario común accede a ello mediante el formulario, que hay en la ruta /password/reset. Esa ruta es llamada por el formulario al darle a enviar.

Comment: de acuerdo entonces lo dejare asi, ultima pregunta donde se encuentra el mail que se envia al resetear la contraseña, donde esta alojado?

Comment: El email se envia al correo de la cuenta que quieres recuperar, si estas preguntando por como se envia el correo, Laravel te permite configurarlo en config/services.php.

Comment: no lo que pregunto es donde esta alojado con el texto en ingles, en que clase?

Comment: creo que se llama ResetPassword.php bajo que carpeta lo encuentro?

Comment: Si buscas la vista que manda el correo. Necesitas correr este comando en la consola: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications` Y te aparecen nuevas vistas en resourcers, ahi la encontraras.

Comment: y puedo modificar directamente dicha vista o no seria lo correcto?

Comment: Claro, al ejecutar el comando recibes esas vistas para modificarlas a tu antojo.

Comment: gracias por fin voy a poder terminar el metodo auth